# Is it now possible to write an answering machine app in android?

Tags: android

I know this is a duplicate question. But in all of them the answer is NO!
But there is some Apps like [Answering Machine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.elpis.answer_machine) or [Sanity](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cri.sanity&hl=en) that already doing this. So my question is that is it now possible to:

1. Automatically answer to the incoming call
2. Play a prerecorded audio
3. Record a message

with Google APIs. Needing to rooted ROMs is not a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible with Google's API, however as far as I know you can achieve it with Reflection, and hacking, but there is no solution that would work on every device.

http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.hu/2010/09/call-control-in-android.html

It is oficially possible with custom ROM, you can expose the hidden "api" so you don't need to use reflection, but believe me, you don't want to dig into that:)